# MomentJS Time is returning an unexpected result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm attempting to have the time of Australia display (UTC +11 offset, 39600 in seconds),
but for some reason whenever I go to display the time with the moment.unix().format() operator, the time is hours off.

```
const moment = require('moment');
const timestamp = moment().unix()
const australia_offset = 39600

console.log(`${moment.unix(timestamp + australia_offset).format('hh:mm a')} | ${timestamp} | ${australia_offset}`);
```

Does anybody have any clue why this is happening and how I could fix it? I've been trying to figure this out myself for a while and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Note:
When I attempt to run the data through another converter, it shows up with the proper time, so I'm 100% sure the addition isn't wrong.

Comment: Not sure if this is something that moment generally has trouble with, but even moment's docs say you shouldn't really use moment anymore - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ I'd go with datefns instead - https://date-fns.org/